# Is there any CSS3 auto backward compatibility generator?

Tags: css, webkit

I usually use CSS3 properties in my style sheets. Older browsers requires special prefixes to get the same results as the new ones. Is there any way to leave unnecessary prefixes but get the same result as with them?

Solid CSS3 property:

```
border-radius: 1px;
```

For compatibility:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 1px;
-moz-border-radius: 1px;
```

I have to use all of them:

```
border-radius: 1px;
-webkit-border-radius: 1px;
-moz-border-radius: 1px;
```

It's hard to maintain 3 unique properties that do the same. I want to work without the compatibility stuff. **My plan is the following**: I work with the simple CSS3 properties and after I'd finish I add the prefixed properties via a automatized program or web application.

**Do somebody know a working solution?** I would appreciate a simple web app.

// border radius, text shadow, box shadow. / Multiple backgrounds, RGBA and other stuff works without annoying prefixes (thanks for god).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using http://prefixr.com/

It even has an API that you can use in your development to help automate the process.

Comment: http://css3please.com is pretty useful in combination with prefixr, i use the two together very happily

Answer (score 1):

If you want a webapp you can use [CSS3 Please!](http://css3please.com/).  It will let you dynamically modify a stylesheet with a live preview.